# How to register a callback for an Activity Result with Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, methods, overriding

**Background**

I am developing an application that needs to browse a file manager , pick an image file and display that in an Android `ImageView` object. The code that starts the image file picker is this one below.

```
private void TextView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //show the file manager with extensions
            Intent image_intent= new Intent(Intent.ActionOpenDocument);
            image_intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
            //set the type for image files
            image_intent.SetType("image/*");
            StartActivityForResult(image_intent, 899);

        }
```

**Problem**

However when I try to override the `OnActivityResult()` method so that I can process the image data from the resulting Intent data, Visual Studio IDE does not list the method `OnActivityResult`, it displays the output below.

[image]

**What I tried**

I tried to check if there is an existing override of this method but there was none.

I also tried to change the return type of the method to see if its been embedded in another return type but couldn't find it.

Why am I unable to override the method and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was using the wrong access specifier to access the method, am supposed to use the keyword `protected override void` and not `public override void`. I had to check with the documentation on Microsoft Docs.